# Automatically add pppoe account to ONT at ZTE Olt c610 terminal

Tags: networking

At ZTEOLT c610.Although I configure ONT by using ZTE Olt c610 to add automatically,I add pppoe account by manually login by ONt webpage.how can I solve ? Explain me , I am beginner in gpon network.

Comment: Acronyms need explanation -- certainly to me.

Comment: The ONT – Optical Network Terminal (also known as the modem) is connected to the Termination Point (TP) via an optical fiber cable. Using an Ethernet cable, it connects to your router and converts light signals from your TP's fiber optic line into electronic signals that your router can understand